# Does a continuous derivative imply differentiability?

Tags: calculus

I am working with the functions 
$f(x)= \begin{cases}
e^x  & \text{if $x<0$} \\
1 & \text{if $0 \leq x<1$} \\
x^2-x &\text{if x>1}
\end{cases}$
and $F(x)$=$\int_0^xf(t) dt$

I know $f(x)$ is integrable but, I find that $F(x)$ is not continuous, even though $F'(x)$ is. I always thought a continous derivative implied a differentiable function, but this doesn't seem to be the case, so is there really a relationship between the continuity of a function and the differentiability of its anti-derivative?

Edit: Ok, I found the problem, I hadn't considered each constant of integration. I guess I had never tried to find an explicit expression for a piecewise function.

Comment: F(x) is continuous, definitely. More than that, it is a differentiable function

Comment: Why do you think $F$ is not continuous ?

Comment: See here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus

Comment: If a function is differentiable at a point, then it is continuous at that point. So does it make sense to speak of $F'$ at $x$ if $F$ is not continuous at $x$?

Comment: Perhaps I am wrong in my application of the FTC, but I get that
$F(x)=\begin{cases}
e^x  & \text{if $x<0$} \\
x & \text{if $0 \leq x<1$} \\
x^3/3-x^2/2 &\text{if x>1}
\end{cases}$
which is clearly discontinuous

Comment: @SantiagoBosch: Check your constants of integration, one for each interval. (They are not arbitrary.)

Comment: So what you're saying is that the constant of integration for each interval comes from treating $f(x)$ as a different function in each interval?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to study $$F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f(t)dt$$

The integral is,

if $x\le 0$ then $F(x)=e^x$

if $0 \le x\le 1$ then $F(x)=x+1$

if $1 \lt x$ then $F(x)=\frac{x^3}3-\frac{x^2}2+2\frac16$

You ignore the constants. F is continuous and differentiable. Your impression is correct. BTW, f or $F'$ is not continuous at x=1.